# Unable to start Zookeeper server in stand alone mode

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am unable to start Zookeeper server in stand alone mode. Getting below error :

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\apache-zookeeper-3.5.6\bin>call  "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\apache-zookeeper-3.5.6\bin..\lo
>   gs" "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE" "-Dzookeeper.log.file=zookeeper-user-server-USER-PC.log" "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=cm
>   d /c taskkill /pid %%p /t /f" -cp "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\apache-zookeeper-3.5.6\bin..\build\classes;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\apache-
>   zookeeper-3.5.6\bin..\build\lib*;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\apache-zookeeper-3.5.6\bin..*;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\apache-zookeeper-3.
>   5.6\bin..\lib*;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\apache-zookeeper-3.5.6\bin..\conf" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "C:\Users\user\AppDa
>   ta\Local\Programs\apache-zookeeper-3.5.6\bin..\conf\zoo.cfg"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

check these things in you config file

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\apache-zookeeper-3.5.6\bin..\lo gs

what's the .. for?

and it would be better to aviod using '.' in windows system.